# How to add a button to RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Peace

I'm trying to add a button that will open a new window in RecyclerView, but it gives me an error in red

> Intent intent = new Intent(**this, MainActivity.class**);
> startActivity(**intent**);

bold marks a red line^^^

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Fly> list;
    public static int idB = 0;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Fly> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view =  LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.userentry,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Fly fly = list.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(fly.getNamefly());
        holder.datefly.setText(fly.getDatefly());
        holder.hourfly.setText(fly.getHourfly());
        holder.contentfly.setText(fly.getContentfly());
        holder.pricefly.setText(fly.getpricefly());
        holder.buttonBUYR.setText(fly.getbuttonBUY());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView name,datefly,hourfly,contentfly,pricefly,buttonBUYR;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textname);
            datefly = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textdate);
            hourfly = itemView.findViewById(R.id.texthour);
            contentfly = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textcontent);
            pricefly = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textprice);
            buttonBUYR = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonBUY);
            itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonBUY).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });


        }
    }
}
```

I have a screen with rows in which each row has properties such as price name and button
I want every button that is pressed to do an action

And I get this error

```
Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener, java.lang.Class<com.example.newp.MainActivity>)'
```

and

```
'startActivity(android.content.Context, android.content.Intent, android.os.Bundle)' in 'androidx.core.content.ContextCompat' cannot be applied to '(android.content.Intent)'
```

Comment: I don't know much about JAVA, but In kotlin, we invoke the click listener inside the init{here}

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to compile your code but since you have a `Context` parameter, I'll assume your'e passing an instance of your activity to it when you initialized your adapter, so change your `Intent` declaration like this, and also use it to call `startActivity`

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
 context.startActivity(intent);
```